# new battery, wear level is 67.7%,16.3%, 8.9%, then 7% at the 3rd charge Cycle, is normal?

Tags: battery, battery-life, microsoft-surface, microsoft-surface-pro, microsoft-surface-pro-4

I just installed an OEM battery on my Surface Pro 4.

At the very beginning, the battery Wear Level is 67.7%.
Then I tested it with discharge and charge cycles. The Wear Level reduces as the following steps:
16.3%, 8.9% then 7%.

During the testing, I found the following status:

If I charge it to full, the Wear Level will be 0.0% and Full Charged Capacity > Designed Capacity. It will keep the same states/numbers during the entire discharging period.

But if I discharge it to empty, the Wear Level will NOT be 0.0% and Full Charged Capacity < Designed Capacity, as shown in the below images. It will keep the same states/numbers during the entire charging period until it is full.

Is this normal? The battery is good or bad?

[1st check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86Tlr.png)

[after 1st cycle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3eYhY.png)

[after 2nd cycle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElZGP.png)

[after 3rd cycle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNLAl.png)

Comment: It looks like the battery controller is learning how much capacity it actually has available. Initially it has no clue, hence it thinks that the battery is massively worn out (67%) then over time the capacity is coming closer to the designed capacity and the "wear" is more normal and relatively low at 7%. For an old battery left on a shelf for years it seems normal-ish, even unused batteries will degrade and the SP4 batteries are likely out of manufacture now so less likely to get a real "new" battery. Only guessing though, hence only a comment. I'd suggest to keep using it as normal and see.

Comment: To add to @Mokubai's comment. It is very common for devices with a Li-ion battery to require some calibration. Usually this is done from the factory, but even over time, calibration may be necessary. The process is usually to fully drain the battery as far as it can go in the device (so the device's minimum state is correctly set) until the device does not power on and not even show any sign of life, and then continuously charge it upto 100%, preferably while powered off. This usually makes it so that your battery indicator is calibrated and the readout is correct.